# Having trouble connecting to my database in android

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

I am remaking my pc application to an android app. The code below works fine in a complete java environment. I am using  mysql-connector for the driver. But when I try it in android onCreate in Main Activity I get a `MySQLNonTransientConnectionException`.

I tried this method with `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` and it gives the same exception. I have no idea how to use logcat so i cant really copy stacktrace. The logcat also says that it cannot create connection to DataBase Server.

```
try {
        Global.AGENDA_CONNECTION = DriverManager.getConnection(Global.URL
                + Global.DATABASE, Global.USERNAME, Global.PASSWORD);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("ggs","Failed to start up");
        return;
    }
```

I have the connecter library both in my libs folder and also in my referenced library folder

Comment: any particular reason as to why you are using mysql as generally people use sqlLIte db for android

Comment: Its the only DB i have experience with... i would give sqlIte a try

Comment: I faced the same issue when I shifted to android from web you have a lot of free tutorials to help you

Comment: Shift to sql lite db

Comment: But it should be able to work inMySql

Comment: post your code where you are creating database